# Assortativity on multiple directed graphs in igraph

Tags: r, igraph

I have a list of edgelists from **directed** networks

```
e_list=list(structure(list(nominator1 = structure(c(3L, 4L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Angela", 
"Jeff", "Jim", "Pam"), class = "factor"), nominee1 = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("Andy", "Angela", "Jeff"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L)), structure(list(nominator2 = structure(c(4L, 1L, 2L, 3L
), .Label = c("Eric", "Jamie", "Oscar", "Tim"), class = "factor"), 
    nominee2 = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("Eric", 
    "Oscar", "Tim"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L)))
```

and a dataframe of attributes for each person in the 2 networks

```
attribute_df=structure(list(names = structure(c(6L, 7L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 8L, 3L, 
4L), .Label = c("Andy", "Angela", "Eric", "Jamie", "Jeff", "Jim", 
"Pam", "Tim"), class = "factor"), gender = structure(c(3L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("", "F", "M"), class = "factor"), 
    happiness = c(8, 9, 4.5, 5.7, 5, 6, 7, 8)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

And I convert them to `igraph` objects

```
if(!require(igraph)) install.packages("igraph"); require(igraph)
graph_list<-lapply(name_of_edgelist_list, graph_from_data_frame)
```

I add the attributes of gender using this loop

```
for(i in 1:length(graph_list)){
  graph_list[[i]]=set_vertex_attr(graph_list[[i]],"gender", value=attribute_df$gender[match(V(graph_list[[i]])$name, attribute_df$names)])

}
```

and the happiness attribute to the graph objects

```
for(i in 1:length(graph_list)){
  graph_list[[i]]=set_vertex_attr(graph_list[[i]],"happiness", value=attribute_df$happiness[match(V(graph_list[[i]])$name, attribute_df$names)])

}
```

When I try to measure assortativity for happiness like this

```
lapply(graph_list, function(x) assortativity(x, V(x)$happiness))
```

I get the first graph's value and then the second graph's assortativity is just 'NA'

Any idea on how I can measure assortativity in these directed graphs?

Comment: When you set the attribute you called it `happiness` but your lapply statement uses `Happiness`. R is case sensitive. Also,  you will get NA for the second graph because you did not supply a value of happiness for Oscar

Comment: @G5W So I cannot measure assortativity if there's missing data? Is there a way I can make the code work with the missing data?